# Sent Monero to Shapeshift

Tags: transaction-data

Mined my first monero.. got 0.42 in three months and was very excited to cash in for some December pocket money but it never arrived shapeshift even though my monero wallet showed it was sent.. that was on Jan 3rd already:(

Was sent to Shapeshift monero address: 46yzCCD3Mza9tRj7aqPSaxVbbePtuAeKzf8Ky2eRtcXGcEgCg1iTBio6N4sPmznfgGEUGDoBz5CLxZ2XPTyZu1yoCAG7zt6

Transaction hash : b3d3799e6bbd64a01c10c5a24ed2dbcf720d9e8f2c2e8326d32d8fbecc154f8c

Monero was sent from wallet :
46joGMni2bodekfqWVte51YgWoDtcCLQHQ1xx4ddsf5UFqekRpqrgBoWbwaVe4vUMveKAzAiA4j8xgUi29TpKXpm41dzPjn

Know it's not a lot but worth almost R2000 in South Africa which is alot:)

Hope someone can help me find it..not sure what else would be needed but will update as required.. holding thumbs

Comment: Did you remember to include your payment Id for shapeshift to identify the 'deposit'?

Comment: Use ^ guide to verify that your transaction arrived correctly. If it did, contact ShapeShift's support.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not include a paymentID shapeshift can not identify you as the payee so will not credit you if this is the case contact their support. I'm afraid your Monero may be lost.